# Drop data from InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I'm not fully understanding the structure of influxDB and I'm wishing to drop some data from it. I have the following:

```
net,agent_host=10.0.1.1,host=debian
net,host=debian,interface=all
net,host=debian,interface=eth0
net,host=dns1,interface=all
net,host=dns1,interface=eth0
net,host=dns2,interface=all
net,host=dns2,interface=eth0
net,host=plex,interface=all
net,host=plex,interface=eth0
```

I've been able to empty the series (?) `net,agent_host=10.0.1.1,host=debian`, but as you can see the value is still listed when I do `show series`.

I don't want to nuke all of the `net` series, but I don't want the index(?) `net,agent_host=10.0.1.1,host=debian` showing up. It adds extra fields in Grafana and I just don't want it.

Can I get rid of this without nuking all of the `net` series?

I dropped the data by issuing: `drop series from net where agent_host="10.0.1.1"`

**EDIT:** Totally forgot. InfluxDB version 1.1.1

Comment: What version of InfluxDB are you using? `DROP SERIES` should remove the series from the index.

Comment: I totally forgot to add it, but it's version 1.1.1.

Comment: Are you writing new data that contains that series? When I run drop series locally, it deindexes correctly, but if I write that series to the database again, it will reappear.

Comment: Good point. I checked many times and it was empty, but it seems like maybe there was a cached value? It did have a few entries that right about the time I was posting this; despite dropping it multiple times. It stopped updating just after I posted this. I dropped it again, and now it's gone.